# RegEx for UK passport numbers does not pick up multiple entries in scan

Tags: regex

I have a regular expressions for UK passport numbers (long number).

```
^[0-9]{10}GBR[0-9]{7}[U,M,F]{1}[0-9]{9}$
```

Which I have tested in https://regex101.com/r/MqTflJ/1 in golang.

However, in the scan where I am using the RegEx it is not finding multiple entries.

Is there a better RegEx for me to find multiple UK passport entries as another problem I am facing is capturing 10 digit phone numbers in my RegEx?

Any help appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: What number do you have that isn't matching?

Comment: Can you put your sample text?

Comment: So the matches work in the RegEx tester:

https://regex101.com/r/MqTflJ/1

(I have used example text in there)

But I am doing data loss prevention scanning on my network to find U.K. passport numbers and my scan is not working with this RegEx I have provided ^^.

I want to know if there is better (more complex or simpler) RegEx to use?

Thanks!

Comment: `6098475322GBR6911225F140517400`

Answer (score 0):

This expression works best for long passport numbers:

> `[0-9]{10}[a-z]{3}[0-9]{7}[U,M,F]{1}[0-9]{9}`

Using the **g**, **i** and **m** flags.